# Unknown column type "money" requested

Tags: php, symfony, types, doctrine-orm, currency

I want to add to my form, under Symfony2 framework, a field to hold a price of product.

When I use the type integer, I see that the field has up-down arrows (in Chrome) and can have negative values. What I need is a normal field. I tried the type money, but I have the following error:

```
Unknown column type "money" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypeMap().
```

I tried:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\MoneyType;
```

But in vain

How can I register the type money? 
Or I should use a normal text field with some  validatinn?
Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from [Symfony2's documentation](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/forms/types/money.html):

```
$builder->add('price', 'money', array(
    'divisor' => 100,
));
```

Did you try this? Perhaps you make a typo somewhere?